# How does Saadia Gaon explain עדה וצילה?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, parashat-bereishit, saadya-gaon, avraham-ibn-ezra

אבן עזרא על בראשית ד׳:י״ט:א׳ implies that Saadia Gaon has an explanation of the names עדה וצלה. Do you know where I could find that?

Comment: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Parshan/R._Saadia_Gaon_Commentary/Bereshit/4.18#m7e0n6 but I don't see where he interprets the names

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Saadia_Gaon_on_Genesis.4.23.1?vhe=Saadya%27s_Commentary_on_Genesis,_New_York,_1984&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Shmuel I don't see an explanation of the names עדה וצלה there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it but it's a little obscure. Bereshis Rabbah on 4:20 says that the reason for the names is that Adah was the first wife, bearing children,  while Tzila waited in Adah's *tzel* (shadow). Saadia Gaon on the passuq assumes that this is true and deals with secondary questions. Ibn Ezra says, don't worry about all that because we don't even know that it's true.

Comment: Where do you see in RaSaG that he’s assuming the interpretation of the midrash?